# Loading Parquet File into a Hive Table stored as Parquet fail(values are null)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark, impala

I am simply trying to create a table in hive that is stored as a parquet file, and then transform the csv file that holds the data into a parquet file, and then load it into the hdfs directory to insert the values.below is my sequence that I am doing but to no avail:

First I created a table in Hive:

```
CREATE external table  if not EXISTS db1.managed_table55 (dummy string)
stored as parquet
location '/hadoop/db1/managed_table55';
```

Then i loaded a parquet file into the above hdfs location using this spark:

```
df=spark.read.csv("/user/use_this.csv", header='true')
df.write.save('/hadoop/db1/managed_table55/test.parquet', format="parquet")
```

It loads but here is the output......all null values:
[image]

Here is the original values in the use_this.csv file that I transformed into a parquet file:
[image]

This is proof that the specified location created the table's folder(managed_table55) and the file(test.parquet):
[image]

[image]

Any ideas or suggestions as why this keeps happening? I know there's probably a minor tweak but I cant seem to identify it.

Answer (score 2):

As you are writing parquet file to `/hadoop/db1/managed_table55/test.parquet` this location Try creating table in the same location and read the data from hive table.

**`Create Hive Table:`**

```
hive> CREATE external table  if not EXISTS db1.managed_table55 (dummy string)
stored as parquet
location '/hadoop/db1/managed_table55/test.parquet';
```

**`Pyspark:`**

```
df=spark.read.csv("/user/use_this.csv", header='true')
df.write.save('/hadoop/db1/managed_table55/test.parquet', format="parquet")
```